# How are error messages in StringTemplate to be interpreted?

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I got this error message while using StringTemplate:

```
line 94:26: unexpected char: ')'
```

And after about 15 minutes of randomly adding and removing blank lines in my template, and observing how the number in that message changed, I finally isolated the line that caused trouble. It was line #152, position #35.

Is the value after "line " just normally totally wrong, or is there a way of deducing the real line number from that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In StringTemplate (ST) 4, it appears that the first number is the line number, within the specific template at issue and not the line number within the .stg file if that's what you're using (which most of us do).

When I'm using vim, this means I need to mentally offset that from the line number of the first line of the template (add them together) to get the actual line number within the .stg file.

The second number in the ST error is the character position within that line of the template. But wait, there's more - you know you love it...

When an error is on the first line of a multi-line template: since ST elides the starting newline in multi-line templates, ST effectively combines the first/ declaration line (ending in "<<") with the second (actual start of the template) line, in multi-line templates;

so at least with ST-4.0.8 I need to subtract the length of the template declaration line from the character position, to get the actual character position.

The first "\n" eliding (for multi-line templates only) also means the line number may appear to be offset by 1, and possibly the character position, for an error on the "first line".

The error should include the filename and template name, so it's enough information for an automated script or tool, but a bit cumbersome for us mere humans.

Good luck.

Comment: I do not use ST anymore, so I'll just have to assume you got it right.